# How many RAM chips of size 256k x 1 bit are required to build 1M Byte memory

Tags: computer-architecture

$$1MBytes =1024*1024*8$$
$$256k*1bit=256*1024$$
$$1MBytes = \frac{1024*1024*8}{256*1024}=32$$

Now my question is that for converting 1MByte to bit level we need 1024*1024*8 but 256K is not converted the same way why (256*1024*8)bit? why we don't multiply with 8 at last since it is kilobyte than byte than bit.

Comment: The left hand side of your last equation seems to be missing information. What are you trying to calculate, exactly?

Comment: We needed the 8 in the first line, since we were converting 1 mega*bytes* into bits. It wasn't needed in the second line since we were converting 256 kilo*bits* into bits.

Comment: Yes, but in the first line you write $1 MB = 1024 \cdot \dots$ while in the third line you get $1 MB = 32$...

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to make a one mega**byte** RAM from a collection of 256 kilo**bit** chips.

Answer (score 1):

No. of RAM chips=1MB/256K=1024x1024x8/256x1024 =32.